# how to get text value or anchor tag value in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am creating a list.but my condition if i want to show those element which start from `hello` else all other element ignore.

can you please tell me how to know what is `anchor text` value ?

here is my code

```
 <Tabs>
      {data.map((i, idx) => (
        <li key={idx}>
          <a>{i}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </Tabs>
```

**my Tabs.js**

```
import React from "react";
export default function Tabs({ children }) {
  const names = () => {
    const namesData = [];

    React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
      console.log(child);
      // if (child?.textcontent?.indexOf("hello")) {
      //   namesData.push(child);
      // }
      namesData.push(child);
    });
    return {
      namesData
    };
  };
  const { namesData = [] } = names();
  return <ul>{namesData.map((i) => i)}</ul>;
}
```

NOTE : **there is one solution to filter data initially while doing iteration using map.but I don't want to use this  that solution**

can we add here condition if child anchor tag has `hello` text then only I push in array

```
 React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
          console.log(child);
          // if (child?.textcontent?.indexOf("hello")) {
          //   namesData.push(child);
          // }
          namesData.push(child);
        });
```

**whole code**
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-goldberg-ey2lc?file=/src/tabs.js:0-460

Comment: The right solution is the one you don't want to use

Comment: @Ibsn .. I want to use ref solution

Answer (score 0):

Since children are react elements, they have `props`, which you can access. The `props` might contains `children` as well, and so on. Specifically for your use case, this would work ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-newton-gb3ql?file=/src/tabs.js)):

```
React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
  const content = child.props?.children.props?.children;

  if(typeof content === 'string' && content.startsWith('hello')) {
    namesData.push(child);
  }
});
```

However, I wouldn't go that way. This seems to be brittle, and dependent on the way React decides to model children. A better option would be to filter the original array to include only the data for the items, you wish to render ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-lamarr-zf3b7?file=/src/App.js)):

```
<Tabs>
  {data
   .filter(txt => txt.startsWith('hello'))
   .map((i, idx) => (
    <li key={idx}>
      <a>{i}</a>
    </li>
  ))}
</Tabs>
```

Comment: thanks for answering ,, can we give `ref` to child and using `ref` can we do that

Comment: Yes, you can, but ref is a direct reference to the actual DOM element, not the react child, so you'll need to use DOM tools to remove/hide, which is not a good idea in react. Just filter the original array.

Comment: can we do like that ..!!

Comment: can you update your answer . i haven't use ref

Comment: can we give ref to all child element .. then using ref can we get content value ? how to give refs to childs ? how to access using ref

Answer (score 0):

Just like that

```js
import React from "react";
export default function Tabs({ children }) {
  const names = () => {
    const namesData = [];

    React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
      if(child?.props?.children?.props?.children.startsWith('hello')) namesData.push(child);
    });
    return {
      namesData
    };
  };
  const { namesData = [] } = names();
  return <ul>{namesData.map((i) => i)}</ul>;
}
```